# Serialization in Unreal vs Unity

Tags: serialization, properties, macros, unreal-engine4

In **Unity** you have to tell the engine which are the parameters to serialize.
Not only that, some of them are not serializable (like dictionaries, for instance), and you need to specify it very clearly and carefully.

I'm really confused to find nearly **no documentation** in any book or official page about it. Not even questions in the forums. Seems like a blueprint thing only... and not really it.

What I need to know if the state of the **editor variables state are stored** in the scene when you save it (serialized) and also when you enter Play Mode.

How about **creating instances of a component whose UPROPERTIES values are also set in the editor but created using Macros from other files**. Those are quite dynamic. Are those stored too? 
(I understand that the constructor is executed everytime you open the scene. I'm only interested in this case... not creating the instance via code, since you can set those values hardcoded)

I'm running tests, but would help some information about all this. Maybe Unreal stores every single thing and that's why there's no info about it...

Comment: In fact, I add here a link to another question I just posted about SerializeText UPROPERTY parameter which is a little undocumented and surprisingly doesn't compile. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45937658/how-to-use-uproperty-serializetext
That's the only thing I found about serialization on Unreal...

Comment: In Unity, by default, every type marked as `[Serializable]` is ( as name says ) serializable. There's difference between inspector visibility and serialization, so Unity ( again, by default ) shows only `public` and `[Serializable]` `field`s. You can decorate `private` `field`s with `[SerializeField]` to make them visible.

Comment: hey @m.rogalski, is that an answer?: I'm asking how to do this in Unreal, not Unity.

Comment: If it would be an answer It would not be placed in a comments section. My comment is just a clarification for your statement about serialization in Unity.

Comment: Oh cool! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know about UE serialization, variables marked with `UPROPERTY` macro are subjects to a **CDO** mechanism (or at least those marked as EditDefaultsOnly, EditAnywhere and similar Attributes that lets you edit it's value in editor). *CDO* is *Class Default Object* and basically it holds initial data for UObjects.

Values of those properties could be set in C++ or editor and later changed (**overridden**) on actual *instances* or defaults of *derived classes* (meaning Blueprint classes as well). If you don't want to store value of a property, you can use `Transient` flag (c++) or checkbox (BP). I often use it for cached items which I find during gameplay.

Note, that in C++ constructor, those properties are not correctly initialized. And they are not correctly initialized until `PostInitProperties()` is called, which is after *CDO* initialization.

I found usefull reading about Actor's lifecycle [UE Docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Actors/ActorLifecycle/) and it helped me a lot.

Comment: Oh man, that's gold. I've read literally everything but never about this. Documentation is quite impossible to follow when you are new to game engines. Thanks a lot!